# Solving an Algebraic Loop in Simulink using an Initial Value

Tags: matlab, simulink, transformer-model

I am building a circuit model for a transformer which models the effects of hysteresis. It does so using the Matlab function block on the right, and works successfully when tested in isolation. However, the value of the magnetising inductance Lm depends on calculations requiring the value of Im. But Simulink cannot determine the value of Im without the value of Lm, thus forming an algebraic loop.

However, I have the initial value for the inductance, Lm_initial loaded into the workspace. With this, I should be able to solve for the first Im value, which can be used to determine the next Lm, and so on. However, specifying Lm_initial in the variable inductor's properties doesn't work; Simulink tries to evaluate Lm with the nonexistent 'phi' and 'Im' values rather than trying to solve for an initial Im using the value of the initial inductance.

I have tried solutions involving commenting/uncommenting blocks and implementing further subsystems which activate/deactivate depending on the time step, as well as unit delays, but these run into issues regarding tracking time for calculating the derivatives or output very incorrect/noisy waveforms.

Is there a relatively simple solution for this case? The problem appears as if it'd be relatively simple to solve, but I cannot seem to find a workaround for this.

[Transformer Equivalent Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JbuH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The exact placement of the unit delay in the loop might be the key here: try to place the unit delay between the `[lm]` GoTo block and the `lm` input of your MATLAB function block `fcn`, that should work. And set the [initial condition parameter](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/unitdelay.html#brp132n-7) to `Lm_initial`.